# About navigation

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have two pages.
On First Page, when user clicks on button1, the foll. code executes..

```
{
 MessageBox.Show("1");
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
 MessageBox.Show("4");
}
```

The PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded event on 'Page1.zaml' contains foll. code...

```
{
  MessageBox.Show("2");
  MessageBox.Show("3");
}.
```

But its showing "1","4", then control goes over Page1.xaml & then MessageBox "2" & "3" are displayed.
Suppose I want the output like Message Boxes containing "1 2 3 4" sequentially, then whats the solution, plz help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer Full Control (Navigation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593026/transfer-full-control-navigation)

Comment: If you are abondoning this question due to writing it inaccurately, please remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely surprised - I suspect the `NavigationService.Navigate` command is basically adding a "please navigate" command to the queue of UI events, rather than doing everything immediately.

If you want something to happen after navigation has completed (like the message box in this case), try subscribing to the [`NavigationService.Navigated` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigated%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). (You'll need to check whether that fires before or after the `Page.Loaded` event though.)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what's going on here.. I'll combine in with Jon on this one. This thread gives you a bit of an idea of MessageBox and Storyboard shenanigens going on that are yet to be explained. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/77ec9eca-07f0-4a90-aaaa-f3781331a61e

Comment: Reread the question, it's fairly clear each method is just executing sequentially.

Comment: @Mick: I'm not sure whether you're saying that *you've* just reread the question, or suggesting that I do so :)

Comment: Sorry Jon, poor choice of words.. that was my comment from my rereading of the question :) Suggesting that it's likely not as much an issue as the thread I linked earlier.