# Transfer Full Control (Navigation)

Tags: windows-phone-7

My question was little diff.
From MainPage.xaml, I am using 'NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));'. It does not goes to Page1.xaml immediately. It just creates an Now the control does not completely goes to Page1.xaml. It again starts execution what is written on the next line to NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative)).

I have to transfer full control towards Page1.xaml, when I return from Page1 then it must resume the remaining execution of MainPage.xaml.
Plz Help.

Answer (score 0):

Navigating to another page is not a synchronous process where you call the page and wait for a return result.

When you pass control to another page, it is effectively something that you fire off and forget.

Any subsequent processing you want to do when you get control back in the original page should be handled in one of the corresponding events/overrides for that page - Loaded, OnNavigatedTo for example.

Answer (score 0):

So when the user *navigates back* from Page1, you want to do something on MainPage? Override [OnNavigatedTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=VS.92%29.aspx#) in MainPage and handle the navigation that way. I don't think there's a really elegant way to determining that the navigation was due to a "backward" navigation - you may need to use `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State` to work that out.

Note that this due to tombstoning etc, this could be a different instance of MainPage from the original one.

Either way, you won't be able to just continue from where you left off *within a method*. You need to think in a more event-based way.