# Synchronized Navigation

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any trick to navigate on other page through synchronous process?

Comment: What part of this has to do with programming?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer Full Control (Navigation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593026/transfer-full-control-navigation)

Comment: This appears to be the 5th incarnation of the same question in the past 12 hours. Please remove your duplicates, and respond to the answers originally given to you if you need more clarification. If you would like to provide more information, please do so by editing the original question with an UPDATE / EDIT for the extra information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is linked to your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593463/about-synchronized-navigation).

Synchronous process are (generally) bad for perceived performance. This perception is amplified on mobile diveices (such as phones).

Because of this, most operations on WP7 happen asynchronously. As a general rule you should learn to work with this behaviour rather than against it as it's there for a reason.

If you have a specific issue where you wish to perform an operation synchronously then post the specific details and we'll advise accordingly.