# About Synchronized Navigation

Tags: windows-phone-7

MainPage.xaml's Button1_Click event contains

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
postPhotoToFacebook();
```

Page1.xaml contains webbrowser (all aunthentication, authorization acitivities, login page etc.).

When user clicks Button1, the control is navigated to Page1.xaml.
Before finishing entire acitivities on Page1.xaml, it returns back to MainPage.xaml & executes `postPhotoToFacebook().`

Plz help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer Full Control (Navigation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593026/transfer-full-control-navigation)

Comment: This appears to be the 3rd incarnation of the same question in the past 12 hours. Please pick one, and respond to the answers people are giving you if you need more clarification. If you would like to provide more information, please do so by editing the original question with an UPDATE / EDIT for the extra information

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what `postPhotoToFacebook()` does it's hard to say for sure, but I'm guessing that it contains some functionality relating to whatever is in `Page1.xaml`

As a general rule you shouldn't perform operations in a method after you `Navigate`.

If you need to perform an operation in the background (such as communicating with Facebook) then you should do this in a separate thread. Either by creating a specific BackgroundWorker or a thread that runs in the background. You could also start the process asynchronously with a callback which runs off the UI thread.

If your posting of the photo to Facebook is related to or dependent upon `Page1.xaml` or it having loaded then you should do this in a method triggered by an event of that page. (`NavigatedTo` or `Loaded` are probably the most appropriate).

If you just want to begin the uploading process and then navigate to `Page1` then you could do this before calling `Navigate()`.